# React - Generic component that is content agnostic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to create a toasting mechanism (without an external library), in which I am not aware of what content passed to it. It can be a string or custom HTML.

In addition, I would like to make it accessible via API:

`toast.notifyError('some Error')` or `toast.notifyError(<div>Some error with a <button /></div>)`

I created a `useToast` hook that has pretty much the following structure:

```
const useToast = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  ...
  // add the toast
  const notify = useCallback(() => ....);

  const { items, notify };
}
```

And I access the `notify` method through **context** in every other component.

**The problem**: as far as I know, keeping the HTML content within the hook state is wrong. How can I overcome this? is there a smart way of doing such thing without keeping HTML in state?

Comment: Seems you could pass *anything* renderable to the `notify` methods and pass them to the JSX/notification component to be rendered as `children`. Can you provide a more complete code example for what you've tried?

Comment: @DrewReese that's exactly the question, is this considered wrong to pass `jsx` for instance?

Comment: You pass JSX as `children` prop all the time in React, why would this be *much* different?

Comment: @DrewReese The Problem is that the component rendering the toasts is somewhere else in the tree and in different places you want to add toasts using the method from the hook. So you need to "remember" the components or elements to render somewhere as they do not get rendered where they get added.

Comment: @DrewReese exactly. So what would be a nice approach for that?

Comment: Pass the renderable content to the notification component to be rendered as children. How are you rendering your notifications? I think either I'm not understanding what you think the issue is, or you're not understanding what I mean by passing children to react components.

Comment: @superuser123 you could keep a list or map of render functions in a ref and call them in the `Toaster`.

Comment: @DrewReese There is a single component somewhere that renders the current notifications and other components add notifications by calling the `notify` function provided by the `useToast` hook, e.g. in a handler. You must have a way to remember the components or elements to render inside the compponent rendering the toasts (call it `Toaster`) and the question was if it is okay to store them in state or if there is a different way of doing it.

Comment: @trixn I understand that, that's exactly how toasters, modals, etc... all generally function. I made a suggestion then asked for more context from OP how they are consuming what they want displayed to see what/where/how any further suggestions/improvements can be made. The simplest way is to create a portal on-demand and render the content, skipping storing anything in state. Maybe that is enough, maybe OP needs more.

Comment: @trixn this is the direction I thought of. Basically it feels more right but of course adds some complication for the naked eye. Anyway, feels better than state, doesnt it?

Comment: @DrewReese And who is responsible for mounting and unmounting the portals? Who keeps the render tree of that if a toast is only added by calling a `notify` function? Some component needs to know the contents to render into the portals and remove them when e.g. the display time is up.

Comment: @trixn Likely the component code I kindly suggested should be included in the question so we could see what superuser123 is working with, right? How about you ease up a bit.

Comment: @DrewReese I'm totally easy. I just wanted to help clearify things. But yeah, OP should probably include the component rendering the toasts. But it's implied by the _"And I access the notify method through context in every other component"_. There must be a single component rendering all the toasts if they get added by just calling a function. This is also how basically any toaster lib works. And if that is the case calling  `notify` must lead to a re-render of that component. So how does the component remember how to render the toasts.

Comment: FWIW I don't see much an issue with temporarily storing string primitives or JSX literals in component/hook state, to be rendered into what is essentially an "alert". IMO I think you are conflating the issue of storing instantiated react components in state which can lead to stale state & callback enclosures, in other words, the state is a bit more long-lived and becomes stale. With toasts, by nature, they are very transient... they "mount", are displayed for a short duration, and "unmount"/go away, and the content shouldn't be interactive, the toast container is.